# How to turn off Android Studio 3.0 Labels?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 and I noticed that there's strange labels / tags all over my code.  I can't manually delete these labels since the cursor just jumps right over them.  How do I turn off these labels??  Android Studio has different menus and commands than IntelliJ.

[image]

Comment: Give them a chance :) they are really useful

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question.  The other question was for intelliJ, this question is for Android Studio.  The commands and menus to disable this in intelliJ are totally different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Android studio 4
Go to `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inlay Hints`

> Credit goes to @Quintin Willison in the comments of this answer

For earlier versions

Got to `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` >`Appearance`
And remove tick from this option

`Show Parameter name hints`

[image: Disable code hint]

Comment: Android Studio 4.0 seems to have renamed these "Inlay Hints" and the check box to disable them can be found at `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inlay Hints`.

Answer (score 1):

press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you are in that line and select "Do not show hints for current method"

further infos [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205418670-How-to-disable-parameter-hints-for-constructors-only-)