# Android - How to toggle between XML showing variable name & value?

Tags: android, android-studio

I noticed that in the latest version of Android Studio - XML variables of the form `@string/something` or `@dimen/something_else` are automatically displayed as their respective values.

How do I toggle this feature on and off?

[image]

Comment: Tap on it and it will turn into the actual string.  I'm sure there's a setting somewhere under editor settings

Comment: @GabeSechan I am very well aware of that. But I cannot seem to find the corresponding setting. Which is why I am asking.

Comment: @AlanSTACK How about looking into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037076/how-to-turn-off-android-studio-3-0-labels)